# RPI not responding to SD card

Tags: sd-card, noobs

I have a Raspberry PI 3 and I want to install Kali Linux onto it. I downloaded the RPI image file from https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/. Then, using Win32 Disk Imager, I wrote the image onto my micro SD card. I put my SD card into my RPI, plugged it into a monitor through VGA with a HDMI adapter, then plugged in the power cord for my RPI. All I got was a blank screen from my monitor and a red light from my RPI.

The monitor sensed that there was something plugged into it but that was all. My micro SD card has 32GB space and I received it with NOOBS preinstalled on it, but deleted it on my card.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience. For me the problem was hdmi output. I added these to config.txt file in the SD card:

```
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```